# Multiple RedactedFields in AWS WAFv2 put-logging-configuration command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I'm trying to set up logging on our Web ACL with WAFv2.
I can successfully run the `put-logging-configuration` command with one 'RedactedField', but I am having issue adding more headers after the first one.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/put-logging-configuration.html) in question -- I can't quite get my head around it:

> The part of a web request that you want AWS WAF to inspect. Include the single FieldToMatch type that you want to inspect, with additional specifications as needed, according to the type. You specify a single request component in FieldToMatch for each rule statement that requires it. To inspect more than one component of a web request, create a separate rule statement for each component.

Here is my command which works:

```
 aws --region="us-west-2" wafv2 put-logging-configuration \
 --logging-configuration ResourceArn=${MY_WEB_ACL_ARN},LogDestinationConfigs=${MY_FIREHOSE_DELIVERY_STREAM_ARN},RedactedFields={SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}}
```

This gives the following result:

```
{
    "LoggingConfiguration": {
        "ResourceArn": "{My arn}",
        "LogDestinationConfigs": [
            "{My firehose log stream arn}"
        ],
        "RedactedFields": [
            {
                "SingleHeader": {
                    "Name": "cookie"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I also wish to redact the "authorization" header.

I have tried the following as part of "RedactedFields" portion of `--logging-configuration`:

```
1) Two SingleHeader statements within brackets
RedactedFields={SingleHeader={Name="cookie"},SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}}
(Results in 'Unknown options' error.)

2) Two sets of brackets with comma
RedactedFields={SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}},{SingleHeader={Name="authorization"}}
Error parsing parameter '--logging-configuration': Expected: '=', received: '{' for input:

3) Two sets of brackets, no comma 
RedactedFields={SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}}{SingleHeader={Name="authorization"}}
Error parsing parameter '--logging-configuration': Expected: ',', received: '{' for input: 

4) Two SingleHeader statements within brackets, no comma
RedactedFields={SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}{SingleHeader={Name="authorization"}}
Error parsing parameter '--logging-configuration': Expected: ',', received: '{' for input:

5) One SingleHeader statement, two headers (Isn't really a SingleHeader anymore, is it?)
RedactedFields={SingleHeader={Name="cookie", "authorization"}}
Unknown options: authorization}}
```

What am I getting wrong here? I've tried many other ways including `[]` square brackets, multiple instances of 'Name', multiple instances of 'RedactedFields' entirely -- none work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add multiple SingleHeaders to RedactedFields via shorthand-syntax, I had to

- Give each SingleHeader it's own set of brackets
- Add a comma between each bracket set
- Wrap all of the sets with square brackets
- Wrap everything in single quotes.

For example, if I wanted two SingleHeaders, one for 'cookie' and one for 'authorization', I would need to use the following for the `RedactedFields` portion of `--logging-configuration`:

```
RedactedFields='[{SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}},{SingleHeader={Name="authorization"}}]'
```

In conclusion, if we add this to put-logging-configuration, the whole command would be:

```
aws --region=${MY_REGION} wafv2 put-logging-configuration \
--logging-configuration ResourceArn=${MY_WEB_ACL_ARN},LogDestinationConfigs=${MY_FIREHOSE_DELIVERY_STREAM_ARN},RedactedFields='[{SingleHeader={Name="cookie"}},{SingleHeader={Name="authorization"}}]'
```

Giving the following result:

```
{
    "LoggingConfiguration": {
        "ResourceArn": "{my acl arn}",
        "LogDestinationConfigs": [
            "{my firehose log stream arn}"
        ],
        "RedactedFields": [
            {
                "SingleHeader": {
                    "Name": "cookie"
                }
            },
            {
                "SingleHeader": {
                    "Name": "authorization"
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

This formatting can be used for any other FieldToMatch, such as SingleQueryArgument, AllQueryArguments, QueryString, UriPath, Body, etc.